# Data not convert into Base64

Tags: jquery, webcam

I'm trying to  use  image captured with webcam and want to show over webpage and want to store that also.Here My code trying to convert captured image into Base64 format but it is failed to convert into Base64.Kindly give me solution how can i convert this into Base64.

My code is:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="/static/webcam/New/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">   </script>      
    <script src="/static/webcam/New/webcam.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function showWebcam(){ 
            $("#camera").webcam({
                width: 320,
                height: 240,
                mode: "callback",
                swffile: "/static/webcam/jscam.swf",

                quality: 100,

                onCapture:  function () {
                },
                onTick:     function () {},
                onSave:     function () {},
                onLoad:     function () {},

                debug: function(type, string) {
                    $('#wcStatus').append(type + ": " + string + '<br /><br />');
                }      
            }); 
        }


        function capture_image(){ 



            void(0);

            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            //                var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            var img = canvas.toDataURL();

            alert(img);
            var item_image = img.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "") ;
            alert(item_image);


            document.getElementById('myImg').src=item_image;

        }


    </script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="camera"></div>    
    <div id="camList"></div>
    <div id="wcStatus"></div>    
    <button onclick="showWebcam();">Use Webcam Instead</button>    
    <button onclick="javascript:capture_image();">Take a picture!</button>
    <div id="capture_images"><input id="capture_image" type="hidden" value=""    name="capture[image]"></div>

    <img id="myImg" src="face.png" border=1> 
    <p><canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="240"> </canvas>

    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is going wrong? "It failed to convert, kindly give me solution" is not a very good problem description.

Comment: I want Base64code by using capture_image() function and want to display image at webpage.But i'm fail to do so.

Comment: What fails? Where are you not getting the correct result?

Comment: I think canvas.toDataURL(); should return base64code.